# Why does DOMException constructor directly derive from Function.prototype but DOMException.prototype directly from Error.prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain, domexception

In other words, why isn't DOMException like AggregateError, EvalError, etc?

[image: devtools evaluation screenshot]
Both expressions evaluate to true:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(DOMException) === Function.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(DOMException.prototype) === Error.prototype
```

I used to think the following generalization has no counterexamples:

If

- X and Y are constructor functions, and
- Y is not the Object() constructor, and
- X.prototype has Y.prototype as its [[Prototype]] object
  Then
- X has Y as its [[Prototype]] object

For example, the above generalization holds for the following X,Y pairs

1. HTMLElement, Element
2. AggregateError, Error
3. AsyncFunction, Function
4. Node, EventTarget
5. Element, Node
6. RTCError, DOMException

The only case I know of in which the generalization fails is when X = DOMException and Y = Error.

Is there a deeper reason why the DOMException constructor itself cannot have the Error constructor as its [[Prototype]]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If `X.prototype` has `Y.prototype` as its [[Prototype]] object,
> Then `X` has `Y` as its [[Prototype]] object

No, that is not a valid generalisation. It's common, but not ubiquituous. This pattern only started to appear since ES6 `class`es introduced the inheritance of `static` properties (including methods in particular) via the prototype chain. Until then, constructor functions were just plain functions, which inherited from `Function.prototype`. Many libraries still do this.

However, it's true that this generalisation holds for nearly all builtin classes, both native ones (defined by ECMAScript) and host-provided ones (like the DOM). For [the `Error` hierarchy](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-nativeerror-constructors) this was consciously introduced with ES6, in ES5.1 [the native error constructors](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.11.7.5) had still inherited from `Function.prototype`.

For Web APIs, the Web IDL specification [prescribes just this pattern](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#create-an-interface-object) for its interfaces:

2. *Let `constructorProto` be `realm`.[[Intrinsics]].[[%Function.prototype%]].*
3. *If `I` inherits from some other interface `P`, then set `constructorProto` to the [interface object](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-interface-object) of `P` in realm.*

and

3. […] *if `interface` is declared to inherit from another interface, then set `proto` to the [interface prototype object](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-interface-prototype-object) in realm of that [inherited interface](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-inherited-interfaces).*
4. […]
5. *Otherwise, set `proto` to `realm`.[[Intrinsics]].[[%Object.prototype%]].*

Looking at those rules, there's actually a second exception: the `Window` constructor inherits from `EventTarget`, but the `Window.prototype` inherits from a `WindowProperties` object (which in turn inherits from `EventTarget.prototype`).

> Is there a deeper reason why the `DOMException` constructor itself cannot have the `Error` constructor as its *[[Prototype]]*?

No. There's a few likely explanations though:

- it's too old, `DOMException` was part of the first browser js implementations already
- <s>nobody bothered to update it</s>
- it's not web-compatible to update it
- <s>it's just an oversight</s>
- it was updated already but browsers didn't implement it yet

*Edit*: Actually Web IDL explicitly describes it as [an exception to the rule](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#es-DOMException-specialness). It does not `inherit` from `Error`, but it still "*has its [[Prototype]] internal slot set to the intrinsic object `%Error.prototype%`*". This was discussed in [issue #55](https://github.com/whatwg/webidl/issues/55) and [changed in PR #378](https://github.com/whatwg/webidl/pull/378) to align with the implementation reality - away from the previously described [[Prototype]] value of `%Error%`.

Answer (score 1):

Any constructor is inherited from `Function` because it's just a function and has nothing to do with its function's prototype:

```js
class Test{

}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Test.constructor).constructor.name);

function Test2(){

}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Test2.constructor).constructor.name);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Map.constructor).constructor.name);
```